# Why Text element doesn't center vertically inside View?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text, vertical-alignment

Using react-native, I created a custom button as follows:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';

import globalStyles from './../../globals/styles'

import {
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

export default class MyButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.opacitySurface} onPress={this.props.customAction}>
                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.buttonText}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}

let buttonFontSize = 10;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        textContainer: {
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
        },
        opacitySurface: {
            backgroundColor: globalStyles.colors.customerGreen,
            width: "25%",
            height: 60,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 10,
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
            shadowOpacity: 0.8,
            shadowRadius: 1.5
        },
        text: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontFamily: globalStyles.fonts.OpenSans,
            color: 'white',
            fontSize: buttonFontSize,
        }
    }
);
```

But the text inside this button doesn't align vertically. Premise: I am new in react-native and I am almost sure I missing something of really stupid.

[image]

Comment: Try adding style={{textAlignVertical: 'center'}} to opacitySurface view & flex=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the properties  `justifyContent` and `alignItems` to work they need to be on an element with `display: flex`.

Whats making your text align to center is the property `textAlign: 'center'`
on `style.text`

Use `display: 'flex'` and `flex: 1` on your `style.textContainer`

```js
textContainer: {
    display: 'flex'
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
}
```

Comment: @kitsune You can learn more aout flex on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#flex

Answer (score 1):

add css to your opacitySurface

```
display: "flex",
justifyContent: "center",
alignItems: "center"
```

it will make your text in center

Comment: live example https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-knuth-t7did

Comment: you can learn more about flex on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#flex

Answer (score 1):

Add `flex: 1` in your `textContainer` style :

```js
textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
}
```